# N/A data image in rasterizing shapefile with QGIS

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I'm trying to rasterize shapefile on QGIS. However, I got blank image whose max and min value are N/A.

Could someone give advice to me?

I took the following two steps.

1. make field with field calculator via 'open field calculator' icon
   I made int field from a string column as following image
   [image]
2. rasterize image via 'raster' tab -> 'conversion' -> rasterize
   I set the field made in previous step and configured image size: image size units, width and height, then determined its output extent.
   [image]

However I got a blank image and its image has somehow N/A numbers.

[image]

---

P.S.

Here is the output log I got.

```
QGIS version: 3.10.12-A Coruña
QGIS code revision: 75c848ffb1
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.1.4
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Rasterize (vector to raster)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BURN' : 0, 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'EXTENT' : '130.65232439272694,130.82848516072687,32.93750724266676,33.06257376193944 [EPSG:4612]', 'EXTRA' : '', 'FIELD' : 'class', 'HEIGHT' : 100, 'INIT' : None, 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/noguchi_yoshiyuki/Desktop/L03-b-16_4930-jgd_GML/L03-b-16_4930.shp', 'INVERT' : False, 'NODATA' : 0, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'UNITS' : 0, 'WIDTH' : 100 }

GDAL command:
gdal_rasterize -l L03-b-16_4930 -a class -ts 100.0 100.0 -a_nodata 0.0 -te 130.65232439272694 32.93750724266676 130.82848516072687 33.06257376193944 -ot Float32 -of GTiff C:/Users/XXX/L03-b-16_4930-jgd_GML/L03-b-16_4930.shp C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp/processing_5a931e90d0804ebbac791342cdfb5f28/e6a9b2d9826343dcbb88bff6c329a942/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
ERROR 1: Failed to find field class on layer L03-b-16_4930, skipping.

Execution completed in 0.45 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:\\Users\\XXX\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/processing_5a931e90d0804ebbac791342cdfb5f28/e6a9b2d9826343dcbb88bff6c329a942/OUTPUT.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Rasterize (vector to raster)' finished
```

---

P.S. No.2

Here is Type of field I made.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I see no flaws in your workflow. Will you copy the output of GDAL/OGR console, and the log message? Btw, your QGIS may be older than the latest 3.22 (from the look of Rasterize panel, which lacks Burn value option ("Z")).  Could you add QGIS version information, too?

Comment: The coordinate system units are in degrees. What if you try projecting you data in a crs with units in meters, then try rasterizing again

Comment: Can you share your data for testing - at least a sample?

Comment: Could it be that your `class` field does not really contain integers (maybe they were not correctly generated)?

Comment: Mr. Kazuhito >> I added the log at the last part of my question. I hope this helps you check this problem. QGIS version is 3.10.12-A Coruña

Comment: Ms. Bera >> I tried to change its unit to meter by converting it into 'WGS 84 / UTM grid system (northern hemisphere)'. However shapefile image disappeared from my canvas... Actually I'm new to QGIS. If possible could you advice me how to change unit?

Comment: Mr. Babel >> Unfortunately, I cannot put my data here. Instead, you can get similar data on this site: https://nlftp.mlit.go.jp/ksj/gml/datalist/KsjTmplt-L03-b.html.

Comment: Mr. Babel >> I confirmed that class field type is string

Comment: Looking at an error message `ERROR 1: Failed to find field class`, I am now in the same opinion with @Babel that somehow `class` field was not correctly generated. However, QGIS will not allow you to choose `class` field as burn-in value if its type was string. Um ... I have no idea.

Comment: Mr. Kazuhito >> Sorry. I typed wrong information in response to Mr. Babel. The class field type is int, not string. I put the evidence as P.S. No.2 in the end of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested a file from the suggested link https://nlftp.mlit.go.jp/ksj/gml/datalist/KsjTmplt-L03-b.html

Rasterize function went on and on ... quite a long time, and it finally produced a raster, just a partial one.

[image]

Looking at the original data, I realized it was a **Multipolygon** layer!

[image]

Used **Multipart to Singleparts** tool (in the Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry), and re-run Rasterize on the resultant `Single part` layer. It went smooth and produced a raster quickly.

[image]

You should make a complaint against the data provider ([Japanese GSI](https://www.gsi.go.jp/ENGLISH/index.html)) for the lack of information.

Comment: Thanks to your help, I ultimately solved my problem!